# Pass object (variable) to directive angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Controller is called in state.

```
.controller('test', function($scope) {
    $scope.variable = 'Hello';
    $scope.other = 'Hi';
})
.directive('customDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.customDir += ' Word';
        }
    }
});
```

---

```
<input type="text" custom-dir="variable" />
<div>{{variable}}</div>

<input type="text" custom-dir="other" />
<div>{{other}}</div>
```

---

I need that $scope.variable and $scope.other receive " Word", must be able to change the value of passed variable in Directive.

Comment: you want directive to be able to change outer variable?

Comment: Are you asking about a directive that just changes `variable` based on what is typed into the `input` box?

Comment: @CShark In fact I messed example, should put in directive a 'change ". But what I want is simple, I need to change the external variable in directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways. The first one is by using two-way binding:

```
.directive('customDir', function() {
    return {
        scope: {customDir: '='},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.customDir += ' Word';
        }
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/zQOMttjnbvdf6OJNOeoq?p=preview

Another one if you don't need new isolated scope:

```
.directive('customDir', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope[attrs.customDir] += ' Word';
        }
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/FmIy3z4t1SEJQn1YQAkP?p=preview

Comment: The problem with your second approach is what if `attrs.customDir` is "model.variable" rather than just "variable". What I mean is `scope['variable']` works but `scope['model.variable']` won't. I forked your 2nd plunkr to create a version that will handle that case with `$parse`. http://plnkr.co/edit/jj6Ls7SkY6eUYihPdttu?p=info

Comment: @dfsq Perfect!! Just had to put a $timeout in scope variable (customDir) because it was always passing the previous value.